# I found 10 different wallet.dat files on my computer. How can I tell which has money in it? Bitcoin-core-qt

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-qt-setup

In cygwin I did "find / -name wallet*.dat" and found 10 wallet*.dat files on my Windows box.

Some have 2005 dates, some are newer.

Q: How can I determine which one has the money in it?

Comment: Bitcoin didn’t exist in 2005 so that is probably not what you are looking for.

Comment: @Anonymous ...or those files just have wrong dates. Nowadays we have all computers mostly always online and OSes have RTP implemented and ON by default. It wasn't the case 10 years ago so it was possible to have wrong date set up, hence also have files with some ridiculous creation/modification timestamps.

Comment: Can you remember which software you were using at that time? If it is Bitcoin Core you will need to download it, sync the chain and load the wallet.dat into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to have a fully synced bitcoin core on your computer and then load these files one by one. You may need to re-synchronize each time if you use pruning so I suggest to not do that.

Comment: "C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\bitcoin-qt.exe" -datadir=F:\Bitcoin

Comment: i had an external usb drive F: that I forgot about. I plugged it in and changed E to F and it found my coin. I guess it uses the wallet.dat from F: as well... I didnt resync or nothing else, just changed the command properties to F.... Thanks